Is there a way to prove $\sin^{2}{A}+\sin^{2}{B}+\sin^{2}{C}\leq\frac{9}{4}$ for a triangle, without Leibniz's inequality?

Given a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and internal angles $A,B,C$ I want to prove that
$$\sin^{2}{A}+\sin^{2}{B}+\sin^{2}{C}\leq\frac{9}{4}$$

I can do this by using the circumradius of the triangle (proof below), but I want to know if there is an alternative that does not use the Leibniz inequality.
(The Leibniz inequality states that for a triangle with sides length $a,b,c$ and circumradius $R$, $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\leq 9R^{2}$)
By the sine rule:
$$\frac{\sin{A}}{a}=\frac{\sin{B}}{b}=\frac{\sin{C}}{c}=\frac{1}{2R} \tag1$$
So $$\sin^{2}{A}+\sin^{2}{B}+\sin^{2}{C}=\frac{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}{4R^{2}} \tag2$$
And since $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}\leq 9R^{2}$, it follows that
$$\sin^{2}{A}+\sin^{2}{B}+\sin^{2}{C} \leq \frac{9R^{2}}{4r^{2}}=\frac{9}{4} \tag3$$
Is there a way to do this without the Leibniz inequality? Preferably without reference to the circumradius at all...

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are quite a few AoPS threads, not all of which use the Leibniz inequality or circumradius. Also, in the basically equivalent inequality asked about in Prove that in any triangle $ABC$, $\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C\geq\frac{3}{4}$, this answer uses an expansion, multiple & alternate angle formulae, and that the sum of triangle angles is $\pi$. I believe it satisfies your requirements.

Thanks @JohnOmielan - I'll have a look. None of these came up when I was writing the question, but that Approach0 search looks like a useful tool.

Thanks for the edits @Blue. I think the indents and numbering work well.

Let $$\sin^2A + \sin ^2B + \sin^2C=t$$
$$\implies \sin^2A + 1 - \cos ^2 B + \sin^2 C=t$$
$$\implies1 -(\cos^2B-\sin^2A)+1-\cos^2C=t$$
$$\implies2-\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B) - \cos^2 C=t$$
As $A+B+C=π$
$$\implies2-\cos(π-C)\cos(A-B)-\cos^2C=t$$
$$\implies -\cos^2C+\cos(C)\cos(A-B) +(2-t)=0$$
This is a quadratic eqn with respect to $\cos C$. As $\cos C∈R$, $Δ≥0$.
So,
$$\cos^2(A-B)+4(2-t)≥0$$
$$\implies \cos^2(A-B)+8≥4t$$
As $\cos^2(A-B)_{max}=1$,
$$9≥\cos^2(A-B)+8≥4t$$
$$\implies \frac{9}{4}≥t$$
$$\implies  \frac{9}{4}≥\sin^2A + \sin ^2B + \sin^2C$$

No problem. I fooled around with this type for questions a lot during my JEE classes. Have a good day ahead

JEE? I'm Australian, you cannot assume I understand acronyms...

Oh I'm so sorry. It's an entrance exam in India for getting admission in the Indian Institute of Technology. I'm a 12th grader

Here is another solution using vectors:
Let $E=sin^2A+sin^2B+sin^2C$
Note that $2E=3-(cos2A+cos2B+cos2C)$
lemma:  for  $2A + 2B +2C =2\pi, cos2A+cos2B+cos2C>= \frac {-3}{2}$
proof: consider ,3  non parallel unit vectors $\mathbf a, \mathbf b, \mathbf c$(the angles between them are 2A,2B,2C  as A,B,C range from $0-to-\pi$. It is  not  hard  to  see that the expression  is actually the cyclic dot product of the vectors, taken 2 at a time.
ie. $\mathbf {a.b+b.c+c.a}$
but then it is a well known result that the minimum of such a product is -3/2.(actually for a proof you can consider the square of the modulus of the sum of the vectors, and write it as dot products).
Hence, we get our original expression 2E to be less than equal to $\frac 92$.
Or $E<=9/4$.

equality case can be verified easily.

Very nice idea. Thanks.

Take $f(x,y,z)=\sin^2(x)+\sin^2(y)+\sin^2(z)$ defined over the rectangle $[0,\pi]^{3}$. Maximize this function with the constraint $x+y+z=\pi$ using Lagrange multipliers. For that, consider $g(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ and find $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f= \lambda \nabla g$. Then $$\nabla f=(2\sin(x)\cos(x),2\sin(y)\cos(y),2\sin(z)\cos(z))$$ and $$\nabla g=(1,1,1)$$Solve the system
\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\lambda\\
2\sin(y)\cos(y)=\lambda\\
2\sin(z)\cos(z)=\lambda\\
x+y+z=\pi
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

Thanks @CarlosJimenez. I had to remind myself what a Lagrange multiplier was... (it has been a while!). Is there a solution which is more 1st year (or preferably high-school) level? All good if not.

I will think in another more elementary solution!

There may not be one. The suggestion above to use a cos inequality I think will work, I'm just not finished working it through yet. Any ideas are always welcome though.
